# I missed 2 }'sin instagram and am getting an error

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I missed 2 }'s and I put them at the end but I'm getting an error in instagram, I tried them in many places, no use, can anyone know?

```
package com.example.a;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager.NameNotFoundException;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Button dadclink;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        addListenerOnButton();
    }

    public void addListenerOnButton() {
        dadclink = (Button) findViewById(R.id.dadclink);

        dadclink.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @SuppressWarnings("unused")
            public Intent newInstagramProfileIntent(PackageManager pm, String url) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://instagram.com/mzcoco2you");
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
                startActivity(intent);

            } 
};
```

......................

Comment: I did it before and it gave me an error, this time and a few thingies, thank you :)

Comment: I love this type of questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed a "**}**" and "**)**", add them like that:

```
   public class MainActivity extends Activity {

        Button dadclink;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            addListenerOnButton();
        }

        public void addListenerOnButton() {
            dadclink = (Button) findViewById(R.id.dadclink);

            dadclink.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @SuppressWarnings("unused")
                public Intent newInstagramProfileIntent(PackageManager pm, String url) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://instagram.com/mzcoco2you");
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
                    startActivity(intent);

                } 
            });
       }
   }
```

Comment: Thank you so muck Rami!
Can you please tell me what to add in the Manifest? I added some in https://github.com/danthemellowman/instagram-decompiled/blob/master/AndroidManifest.xml but still didn't work

Comment: i don't know exactly what you are doing(or trying to do), to answer your question!